# How can I simplify this using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 vertical sliding panels and I am using the following code for it. Is there any way I can simplify the code?

```
$(".sliding-panels").click(function() {
    var n = $(this).attr("number");

    $(".panel" + n).toggleClass("panel-active");

    if (n == 1) {
        $(".panel2").toggleClass("panel-push-right");
        $(".panel3").toggleClass("panel-push-right");
        $(".panel4").toggleClass("panel-push-right");
    }
    else if (n == 2) {
        $(".panel1").toggleClass("panel-push-left");
        $(".panel3").toggleClass("panel-push-right");
        $(".panel4").toggleClass("panel-push-right");
    }
    else if (n == 3) {
        $(".panel1").toggleClass("panel-push-left");
        $(".panel2").toggleClass("panel-push-left");
        $(".panel4").toggleClass("panel-push-right");
    }
    else if (n == 4) {
        $(".panel1").toggleClass("panel-push-left");
        $(".panel2").toggleClass("panel-push-left");
        $(".panel3").toggleClass("panel-push-left");

    }
});
```

Comment: what is the 'n' variable?

Comment: @Giannis `$(this).attr("number");`

Comment: The community can help you out better if you also include your markup. Or even better, create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about replacing the `if` statement with:

```
var i, toggle_class;
for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    if (i === n) { toggle_class = "panel-active"; }
    else if (i < n) { toggle_class = "panel-push-left"; }
    else /* i > n */ { toggle_class = "panel-push-right"; }
    $(".panel" + i ).toggleClass(toggle_class);
}
```

Comment: Note that I'm using `===` to compare with `n`. This would require that `n` is a number as well. If you want JavaScript to perform implicit conversions, feel free to change that to `==`, or otherwise make sure to use `parseInt` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt).

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit of a stretch, but assuming all the elements have the same class (maybe it even is `.sliding-panels`?) and are in order, i.e.

```
<div class="panel1"></div>
<div class="panel2"></div>
<div class="panel3"></div>
...
```

you can do:

```
var $panels = $(".sliding-panels").click(function() {
    var n = $(this).attr("number") - 1;
    $panels.toggleClass(function(index) {
       return index === n ? 
         'panel-active' : 
         (index < n ? 'panel-push-left' : 'panel-push-right');
    });
});
```

Let jQuery handle the element traversal.